# Code samples don't format correctly after numbered lists

Tags: support, code-formatting

There are three examples that I discovered when trying to post some R code (with carets)

## Example 1

1. List item 1
2. List item 2
3. List item 3

   code sample after list of items.
   it's a two liner
   make that three

## Example 2

1. List item 1
2. List item 2
3. List item 3

   > code sample after list of items.
   >   it's a two liner
   >   make that three

**The output above is different than the bug I discovered. Here's an example of output I saw when I decided to report this bug:**

[image: without horizontal line, with carets]

## Example 3

1. List item 1
2. List item 2
3. List item 3

---

```
> code sample after list of items.
> it's a two liner
> make that three
```

The above is what I'd expect to see (without the horizontal line hack).

Comment: _without the horizontal line hack:_ Just replace it by `<!-- -->`.

Answer (score 3):

You need an extra level of indentation for code samples after lists:

## Example 1

1. List item 1
2. List item 2
3. List item 3

   ```
   code sample after list of items.
   it's a two liner
   make that three
   ```

## Example 2

1. List item 1
2. List item 2
3. List item 3

   ```
   > code sample after list of items.
   > it's a two liner
   > make that three
   ```

## Example 3 - Code flush left

1. List item 1
2. List item 2
3. List item 3

```
> code sample after list of items.
> it's a two liner
> make that three
```

Comment: Gah. And the code samples are indented, rather than being at the main level. An HTML comment is needed if you want the displayed code blocks to be flush against the left margin.

Comment: @Colin'tHart No you don't. See revised answer.